# How to send notifications through google assistant based on custom event?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, ifttt

I have a use case where i want send reminders to my google mini speaker based on events on my calendar. Example: google mini to remind 15 minutes before the event occurs using voice.

trying to figure this out from a long time, without any success. IFTTT doesn't provide an option to select google mini when an event occurs. any help on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications) but only on iOS and Android phones. There is no progammatic way to set reminders for calendar events.

You would have to tell your Google Home Mini "Remind me at (12:45pm) about (my team meeting)" manually.

One potential workaround would be to have some third-party tool which can cast audio to your speaker, although I don't know of one off-hand.